# why do I need grandparent and parent fk in child table (identifying relationship)?

Tags: mysql, relational-database, mysql-workbench

[image]

by default mysql workbench created 2 foreign keys in `stall_images` from parent tables. If I understood identifying relationship correctly - Stall cannot exist without an user (hence identifying relationship), and stall_images cannot exist without a stall (also identifying?).

Why does mysql create both fk in stall_images table, wouldn't stalls fk be enough since stall can't exist without user?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi. What did you tell workbench to get this diagram? PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text.

Comment: @philipxy Hi, this is a screenshot of EER diagram. I'm not quite sure how to describe ERD in text. Link you've sent only talks about code. Do you mean I should upload sql schema or? Thanks.

Comment: 1. In describing text-not-images/links as perhaps limited to code you seem to write as though you didn't read my sentence, the answers (or comments) or multiple links starting with the one I gave. 2. I am sure you will not  need much thought to see what can & should be expressed in text about an ERD. Especially given the preceding. What does the ERD tell you? Write that down. (A subset of DDL.) 3. To reiterate, what did you tell workbench via actions/whatever that got you that diagram? It is the way it is because of your actions & its settings. To answer you we need both those things.